Gibbs sampler for hierarchical model
I am studying MCMC methods and I have the following model
$$
y_i \mid \lambda_i \overset{\text{iid}}{\sim} \text{Poisson}(\lambda_i) \\
\lambda_i \mid \alpha, \beta \overset{\text{iid}}{\sim} \text{Gamma}(\alpha, \beta) \\
\alpha \sim \text{Gamma}(A, B), \quad \beta \sim \text{Gamma}(C, D)
$$
with $\alpha,\beta$ independent.  I want to implement the Gibbs sampler to simulate the posterior distribution. I already determined that
\begin{align*}
    p(\lambda; \alpha ;\beta | y) & = \left( \prod_{i = 1}^{16}  \frac{ \lambda_i^{y_i} e^{-\lambda_i} }{y_i!}  \times \frac{ \beta^{\alpha} \lambda_i^{\alpha - 1} e^{-\lambda_i \beta} } {\Gamma(\alpha)} \right) \times \frac{ B^{A} \alpha^{A-1} e^{- \alpha B}  }{\Gamma(A)} \times  \frac{ D^{C} \beta^{C-1} e^{- \beta D}  }{\Gamma(C)} 
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
    p(\lambda_j | \cdots ) & \sim \mathcal{G}( y_j + \alpha, 1+\beta) \\
    p(\beta | \cdots ) & \sim \mathcal{G}\left( n \alpha + C , \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \lambda_i + D \right)
\end{align*}
but i dont know how is the conditional distribution of $\alpha$, because
$$
p( \alpha | \cdots)  \propto \frac{ \beta^{\alpha n } }{ \Gamma(\alpha)^n } \left( \prod_{i = 1}^{16} \lambda_i \right)^{\alpha - 1}  \alpha^{A-1} e^{-\alpha B}, \quad n = 16
$$
What can I do in this case? I had planned to implement M-H, but I don't know which distribution to choose to simulate. I would appreciate any help and especially references on this topic. Note:
y = c(7,5,9,7,8,9,7,10,7,8,6,8,6,8,5,7)


Yes, MH would do the trick. the most common choice would probably be a truncated normal. A good reference would be any introduction to bayes textbook; I like Peter Hoff (https://sites.math.rutgers.edu/~zeilberg/EM20/Hoff.pdf). But frankly, the Wikipedia page on MH has all you need to get started.

The default is to use a random walk proposal. Since $\alpha>0$, the random walk could be on $\ln\alpha$.
